# Lines on printout of iText7 PDF have different length on paper

Tags: java, printing, itext7

Only some of our testers report a strange look of all lines on the printout of an iText7 generated PDF (see image). The generated PDF looks perfect and the flaw only appears on paper. Most users have no issue, whatsoever.

Any suggestions regarding known issues of printers, drivers or hints on how to reproduce or localize the problem would be appreciated. Anything I could do on iText7 side?

```
PdfCanvas canvas = new PdfCanvas(pdfPage)
canvas.moveTo(x1,y1);
canvas.lineTo(x2,y2);
canvas.closePathStroke();
```

The PDF can be found here: [PDF](https://therapieforum.ch/temp/stackoverflow-20211207.pdf)

[image]

Comment: Please share a PDF for which the error occurs. Furthermore, have you checked whether those users having that issue have something in common that the users without issue don't have, like the same PDF viewer or the same printer, or even the same OS?

Comment: Thanks, I added the link to the PDF to the original message.
All users with this issue
- use Chrome on Windows
- installing and using the Adobe Reader Plugin did not help.
- most of them use a brother printer

Comment: Ok, I can reproduce the issue with your example document, using Chrome on Windows with a Brother printer I also get those extra line segments, using Adobe Reader instead of Chrome I don't. Looking at the PDF, though, I don't see anything that should cause that issue. Consider opening an issue for Chrome. Furthermore, while there is nothing wrong with your kind of line drawing, try drawing the rectangles as rectangles (instead of multiple lines), or use filled thin rectangles instead of lines, maybe one of those options is supported by Chrome printing.

Comment: @mkl Bought an ancient brother printer for testing. I'm now printing thin rectangles instead of lines and it works flawlessly. Thanks for reproducing and the solution. (May I ask you to add your comment as an answer so I can accept it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Making prior comments an actual answer...*

I could reproduce the issue with your example document:

- using Chrome on Windows with a Brother printer I also get those extra line segments;
- using Adobe Reader instead of Chrome I don't.

Looking into the PDF, though, I didn't see anything that should cause that issue.

Thus, while there is nothing wrong with your kind of line drawing to start with, I proposed drawing the rectangles as rectangles (instead of multiple lines), or using filled thin rectangles instead of lines. I hoped one of those options is supported by Chrome printing.

And indeed you commented:

> I'm now printing thin rectangles instead of lines and it works flawlessly.

So, while the bug was not yours from the start, changing your code to draw the borders differently solved the issue for you.